# Displaying multiple languages in single xsl file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I need your help very badly. I am encountering a situation where my java code will get different languages text dynamically and needed to display using xsl.

Most of the times the text will be either English or Arabic only. Currently my code populating some unreadable context on the page and I am not sure how to display them in their original language text.

I will be very thankful if some once can help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Is the text stored in an XML? If you want this to work, you have to store the language in the XML somewhere. Then you can process the text depending on language: if test="@language='ar_EG'" then...

Comment: What XSL-FO formatter are you using?  What have you done to make sure that it will use correct fonts for your Arabic text?  Are you setting `xml:lang` correctly in the FO?

Comment: Thanks for all replies, the scenario I have is I will be calling Rest service from my webapp and getting the JSON response. The JSON response contains list of strings which are sometimes in English, Arabic etc. If it is english we are able to display same. But if it is in Arabic, we are unable to display that in webapp. Cross verified with DHC (Rest Client) and found that JSON is giving correct data only. And I am sorry I don't have an idea  how to use `FO`